# Определить, менялся индексный дескриптор файла после указанной даты. Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Проблема состоит в том что я не знаю какой командой можно определить менялся индексный дескриптор файла после указанной даты. Самое полезное что выдал гугл это https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/linux_base/node73.html где объясняться что из себя представляет дескриптор но примеров проверки его изменения я не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно под «временем изменения файлового дескриптора» понимают `ctime` *change time* — время изменения метаданных. Получить его можно, например, с помощью `stat`, а проверить, например, с помощью `find`:

```
tmp_file="$(mktemp)"
touch -d '1 hour ago' "$tmp_file"
if find /path/to/file -cnewer "$tmp_file" &>/dev/null; then
  echo "inode is newer"
  # ...
fi

rm "$tmp_file"
```

---

См. также: [Случайная статья из гугла про временные метки](https://andreyex.ru/linux/komandy-linux-i-komandy-shell/vremennye-metki-fajlov-v-linux-atime-mtime-ctime-razyasneniya/)